How to configure OAuth for Sveltia CMS in a SvelteKit project with a custom directory structure?
I'm integrating Sveltia CMS with OAuth authentication (using GitHub as the provider) into a SvelteKit-based project, but I'm facing an issue where the /admin route fails after the authentication process. I’m unable to access the CMS admin panel due to a 404 error. The problem seems to lie in the OAuth flow or how it interacts with the website's custom folder structure.
Here’s my project setup:

Repository: Zepp-OS-ScreenReader
Website directory: /site/htdocs
Issue: After initiating OAuth authentication, the system redirects me to a 404 error page instead of loading the CMS admin panel at /admin.

What I have tried:

Configured OAuth in Sveltia CMS, including adding the GitHub client ID, client secret, and the callback URL.
Updated config.yml to ensure it matches the custom directory structure (/site/htdocs).
Verified that the callback URL is correct and aligns with the OAuth settings.

Expected behavior:
The /admin route should authenticate using GitHub OAuth and grant access to the CMS admin dashboard for content management.
Actual behavior:
The system redirects to a 404 error page after OAuth authentication, and the admin panel is not accessible. It appears the issue could be due to the website's folder structure or misconfiguration of the OAuth callback URL.
I have reviewed the official documentation and searched for similar issues online but haven't found a solution tailored to my setup, involving Sveltia CMS, SvelteKit, and a custom directory structure.
Any help or advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!
